# Group by values that are in sequence

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some table like this

```
row chequeNo
 1     15
 2     19
 3     20
 4     35
 5     16
```

and I need to get the result like this

```
row  from   to    
 1    15    16     
 2    19    20    
 3    35    35
```

so I need groups of `chequeNo` where values would be sequential without any interruptions. `chequeNo` is unique column. Additionally it should be done with one sql select query, because I haven't permissions to create any sql structures except select queries.

So is it possible?

Would be grateful for any help

Comment: And the database you are using is?

Comment: Either your example doesn't make sense or I am missing something

Comment: Are you sure that the desired result that you wrote above is correct? I see no pattern in it.

Comment: You should provide a rule which explaings how you need to pick (from) /calculate (to) the values. In the current form no rule can be derived.

Comment: Why does row 3 starts on 35?, shouldn't it start on 20 or 21?

Comment: No, because row 2 already ends on 20. The result says "first unbroken sequence starts at 15, runs to 16. Then 19 to 20. Then just 35 by itself"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! (no `&nbsp;` orgies needed, either!!)

Comment: If there were checkno 17 and 18 added above, would you get one row that had from/to = 15/20?  Do you just want runs where all numbers exist?  Does it matter what is in the "row" column in your results, could that just be left out?

Comment: @juergend
yes, my example doesn't make sense. Real query is very big. In short it is a table of financial cheques and I need to group them in blocks where cheques would have sequential numbers without any interruptions (in scope of one block)

Comment: @LevinMagruder yes, exactly. It would be one row where from=15 and to=20. And no, "row" column is just for numbering of rows

Comment: @marc_s thank you, will keep in mind :)

Answer (score 24):

You can use Aketi Jyuuzou's technique called [Tabibitosan](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3989678) here:

```
SQL> create table mytable (id,chequeno)
  2  as
  3  select 1, 15 from dual union all
  4  select 2, 19 from dual union all
  5  select 3, 20 from dual union all
  6  select 4, 35 from dual union all
  7  select 5, 16 from dual
  8  /

Table created.

SQL> with tabibitosan as
  2  ( select chequeno
  3         , chequeno - row_number() over (order by chequeno) grp
  4      from mytable
  5  )
  6  select row_number() over (order by grp) "row"
  7       , min(chequeno) "from"
  8       , max(chequeno) "to"
  9    from tabibitosan
 10   group by grp
 11  /

       row       from         to
---------- ---------- ----------
         1         15         16
         2         19         20
         3         35         35

3 rows selected.
```

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: +1 thanks giving the name of the technique, that little bit of extra info transforms "here's your answer 1308044" to "here's a general technique you should know."

Comment: thanks a lot. I've integrated this solution to real query and now it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

This should work with Oracle 10 (only tested with Oracle 11)

```
select group_nr + 1,
       min(chequeno) as start_value,
       max(chequeno) as end_value
from (
  select chequeno,
         sum(group_change_flag) over (order by rn) as group_nr
  from (
    select row_number() over (order by chequeno) as rn,
           chequeno, 
           case 
             when chequeno - lag(chequeno,1,chequeno) over (order by chequeno) <= 1 then 0 
             else 1
           end as group_change_flag
    from foo
  ) t1
) t2
group by group_nr
order by group_nr
```

(it should work with any DBMS supporting standard SQL windowing functions, e.g. PostgreSQL, DB2, SQL Server 2012)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "plain vanilla" approach:

```
SELECT T1.chequeNo, T2.chequeNo
FROM Table1 AS T1 INNER JOIN Table1 AS T2 ON T2.chequeNo >= T1.chequeNo
WHERE
NOT EXISTS (SELECT T0.chequeNo FROM Table1 T0 WHERE T0.chequeNo IN ((T1.chequeNo-1), (T2.chequeNo+1)))
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 T0 WHERE T0.chequeNo BETWEEN T1.chequeNo AND T2.chequeNo)=(T2.chequeNo - T1.chequeNo + 1)
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Please let me know if it's too inefficient for large data sets.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE YOUR_TABLE (
    chequeNo NUMBER PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE VALUES (15);
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE VALUES (19);
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE VALUES (20);
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE VALUES (35);
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE VALUES (16);

SELECT T1.chequeNo "from", T2.chequeNo "to"
FROM
    (
        SELECT chequeNo, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY chequeNo) RN
        FROM (
            SELECT chequeNo, LAG(chequeNo) OVER (ORDER BY chequeNo) PREV
            FROM YOUR_TABLE
        )
        WHERE PREV IS NULL OR chequeNo > PREV + 1
    ) T1
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT chequeNo, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY chequeNo) RN
        FROM (
            SELECT chequeNo, LEAD(chequeNo) OVER (ORDER BY chequeNo) NEXT
            FROM YOUR_TABLE
        )
        WHERE NEXT IS NULL OR chequeNo < NEXT - 1
    ) T2
    USING (RN);
```

Result:

```
from                   to                     
---------------------- ---------------------- 
15                     16                     
19                     20                     
35                     35
```

If we spice things up a little...

```
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE VALUES (17);
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE VALUES (18);
```

...we get:

```
from                   to                     
---------------------- ---------------------- 
15                     20                     
35                     35
```