# how to find <N> consecutive sales bonus in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following Table definition with sample data.

Table: target_bonus

```
branch   month    bonus
  1        1       100
  1        2       0
  1        3       200
  1        4       150
  1        5       175
  1        6       180
  1        7       125
  1        8       0
  1        9       0
  1        10      0
  1        11      125
  1        12      130
  2        1       0
  2        2       0
  2        3       200
  2        4       150
  2        5       175
  2        6       180
  2        7       125
  2        8       110
  2        9       105
  2        10      115
  2        11      125
  2        12      130
```

Given the above table, I need to find the N or more consecutive records by month where the bonus is not zero. For example, if N = 3, the result set would return the following:

```
branch     month     bonus
  1        3       200
  1        4       150
  1        5       175
  1        6       180
  1        7       125
  2        3       200
  2        4       150
  2        5       175
  2        6       180
  2        7       125
  2        8       110
  2        9       105
  2        10      115
  2        11      125
  2        12      130
```

Comment: What have you done to find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This builds on this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9977908/330315

Based on that trick, we need to first generate a set of consecutive values that can be used. Then the same approach can be taken:

```
with flagged as (
  select t.*,
         case
            when (bonus > 0) then row_number() over (partition by branch order by month) 
            else 0
          end as bonus_rn
  from target_bonus t
), numbered as (
  select f.*,
         bonus_rn - row_number() over (partition by branch order by month)  as grp
  from flagged f
), grouped as (
  select n.*,
         sum(grp) over (partition by branch order by month) as grp_nr
  from numbered n
), cons as (
  select g.*,
         count(*) over (partition by branch, grp_nr) as num_consecutive
  from grouped g
  where bonus > 0
)
select branch, month, bonus
from cons
where num_consecutive > 1 -- change here if you want 
order by branch, month;
```

The above can probably be simplified, but I find it easier to debug if I can check the result of each step of such an approach.

An alternative query (that resembles more the one in the linked answer) would only display the start and end month for each "interval":

```
with flagged as (
  select t.*,
         case
            when (bonus > 0) then row_number() over (partition by branch order by month) 
            else 0
          end as bonus_rn
  from target_bonus t
), numbered as (
  select f.*,
         bonus_rn - row_number() over (partition by branch order by month)  as grp
  from flagged f
), grouped as (
  select n.*,
         sum(grp) over (partition by branch order by month) as grp_nr
  from numbered n
)
select branch, 
       min(month) as start_month, 
       max(month) as end_month ,
       count(*) as num_consecutive
from grouped 
group by branch, grp_nr
having count(*) > 1 -- change here if you want 
order by branch, start_month;
```

This solution won't be really fast for large tables.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/90b4c/1

Comment: For small N you could just use LEAD/LAG

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help :

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM(SELECT branch, e, f
         FROM(SELECT branch,
                     LEAD(month, 1, 13) OVER (PARTITION BY branch ORDER BY month) - month - 1 AS d,
                     month + 1 AS e,
                     LEAD(month, 1, 13) OVER (PARTITION BY branch ORDER BY month) - 1 AS f
                FROM(SELECT DISTINCT
                            branch, 0 AS month, 0 AS bonus
                       FROM target_bonus x
                      UNION
                     SELECT branch, month, bonus
                       FROM target_bonus x
                    )
               WHERE bonus = 0
             )        
        WHERE d >= 3 -- This is your N
      ) y
  JOIN target_bonus x
    ON x.branch = y.branch
   AND x.month BETWEEN y.e AND y.f
 ORDER
    BY x.branch, x.month;
```

Comment: Mr. DirkNM thanks for your reply... but query take all the data... I want to get only those consecutive month with bonus, like sample to get 3 consecutive month with bonus, month 1,2 with zero bonus, month 3,4,5 with 50 bonus, month 6,7 with zero bonus, month 8,9,10 with 100 bonus and soon.... I want to get only those 3 consecutive month with bonus, so result will be month 3,4&5... month 8,9 & 10

Comment: @empoy The statement above returns the expected result you provide in your question, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/df390/1.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name.... your first query that is what I need.... the problem I'm using older version of oracle 6i forms & Report... any work around that I can use query in oracle 6i version... thanks in advance...

Comment: thanks for your query.... I try it and it works.... one more thing I want only to get the first <N> consecutive month...let N=3 sample january up march has bonus, april upto may zero bonus, june upto august has bonus, sep upto oct zero and the remaining moth has bonus...   so the result it will be... january upto march... since this is the first consecutive...