# Row_num and Partition by DATE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2012, window-functions

I'm struggling to find a solution of doing a `row_number` with `partition by`.

My table looks like this (* this is the only column I have *)

[image]

My script is like this:

```
SELECT 
    [P_ID],
    [DATE],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P_ID,[DATE] ORDER BY P_ID,[DATE] ) AS ROW
FROM #TEMP
```

I want to group by DATE and the first row should say 1 and the second row should also say 1 but the third row should say 2 because the date is(sequentially) 15 then 16 and if there was 17 the row would say 3 but if there was a new row that said 2015-09-21 then it would go back to row 1 and so on....

Is this possible with a partition by?

Comment: *In General*, if you have the same columns in both the `PARTITION BY` and the `ORDER BY`, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: i was going to be sarcastic but then i realized that all answers are good answers so thank you :)

Comment: ignore please, mistake, sorry

Comment: you display 3 different dates in the image, so you will get 1 for each of those three rows (the image and text do not align in details).

Comment: you want to go over multiple rows and check the difference and the assign  value to row column - you need a stored procedure here.

Comment: This should be possible using Tabibitosan - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9977908/610979 for the answer to a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using islands and gaps solution:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( id INT, date DATE )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 2143, '20150902' ),
        ( 2143, '20150915' ),
        ( 2143, '20150916' ),
        ( 2143, '20150917' ),
        ( 2144, '20150902' ),
        ( 2144, '20150903' ),
        ( 2144, '20150916' ),
        ( 2144, '20150917' );

WITH    cte1
          AS ( SELECT   id ,
                        date ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date ) i
               FROM     @t
               GROUP BY id ,
                        date
             ),
        cte2
          AS ( SELECT   id ,
                        MIN(date) mi ,
                        MAX(date) ma ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL
                                                     ) ) rn
               FROM     cte1
               GROUP BY id ,
                        DATEDIFF(DAY, i, date)
             )
    SELECT  t.* ,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY t.id, c.rn ORDER BY date )
    FROM    @t t
            JOIN cte2 c ON t.id = c.id
                           AND t.date BETWEEN c.mi AND c.ma
```

Output:

```
2143    2015-09-02  1
2143    2015-09-15  1
2143    2015-09-16  2
2143    2015-09-17  3
2144    2015-09-02  1
2144    2015-09-03  2
2144    2015-09-16  1
2144    2015-09-17  2
```